# B+ Tree pattern string and full text search

Tags: indexing, data-structures, full-text-search, b-tree

I am studying data structure, and would create a simple design of a database from the beginning, with support for simple CRUD operations.

I have some questions.

First: how data is stored and searched based on a tree structure B +

a) How a string "Every day birds sing with the wind" is stored in the tree?

b) Given a string "birds sing" how it is applied in finding a B + tree question A?

Second question: what is the best alternative algorithms / data structure to create a score by looking at the text, assuming that the same text of the question 1a, return me a higher score to the search for "every" than the search for "very"?

I'm not a megalomaniac, I just want to understand and perform tests of course with a few billion strings, but only for learning purposes.

Comment: Have you done any research on B+ trees thus far? If yes what exactly has you confused

Comment: Yes, and it was not a few. What I'm trying to understand is: the pointers of binary trees point to locations on the hard disk (where the data is stored)?  If so, how are made searches without a read operation on the hard drive to each node?

Comment: Assuming you understand how searching works excluding the disk access part this link may help further your understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688795/how-btree-is-stored-on-disc?lq=1 the searching is done by a key and once you found where the data is stored on the disk a chunk of the data is loaded as a page and then searched/accessed.