# Persistence Strategies for main-memory B+ Trees

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, indexing

I am trying to develop a main-memory index for key-value pairs using C++. I need to make sure the index is recoverable after a crash. I am using a CSB+-Tree implementation (BSD Licence) that I found [here](http://www.cs.illinois.edu/homes/wenpu1/sigmodcontest.html)
The main challenge I am facing is maintaining the parent-child relation data after re-instantiating the nodes.
I have searched for various strategies to save and recover a "tree-structure" to/from a disk. Some of them are:

1. Saving the nodes objects in Pre-order and writing NULLS for empty child pointers.
2. Giving IDS to nodes and saving the ID of a node instead of the pointer while writing
   to disk and then resolving the pointers during re-instantiation using the IDs.
3. Using file-offset values (addresses in physical memory) rather than main memory addresses of the child nodes while saving. This might mean I have to save from leaf-up.

I have also looked at a couple of serialization libraries. Google ProtocolBuffers and Boost Serialization.

Now the "Nodes" in the implementations have a number of pointer variables.Some of these are pointers to other nodes, while others are pointers to "key values". The code below is simplified version to retain the essence.

```
struct NodeHead  
{  
    NodeHead *null; // null indicates internal node  
    char *children; // ptr to children  
    NodeEntry entries[1]; // entry array  
}

struct NodeEntry  
{  
    uint16_t offset;   // offset to NodeHead of the key in byte  
    uint8_t next;   // index of the next entry; 0xff means null  
    uint8_t num;    // [0]: number of entries in use  
};
```

I was thinking of writing the entry values directly into the data for the nodehead rather than saving a link.And giving each NodeHead instance an ID and use that to maintain the "children" relationships. I would like some advice if this can be done in a better way.

Comment: If by crash you are talking of an abortion or any hard interrupt, you won't be able to serialize anything... so what is your strategy to make the data persistent *before* you crash ? Serializing everything at each modification is unlikely to be viable.

Comment: I will not be serializing at each modification. I will be having regular checkpoints. During the checkpoints I will prefer to save a "snapshot" of the index(along with the data in the leaves) to the disk. So that after startup I can recover the index structure. Between 2 checkpoints I will be keeping a log of all transactions, so that I can update the index snapshot after recovery to the latest committed operation. About saving the snapshot to disk, I found a similar question asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872070/saving-btrees-to-a-disk-file-and-read-it . I am stuck on how to proceed

Comment: You can also do option 3, having the index reference itself (no pointers just references to page offsets - allocate the index in pages), then when you come to snapshot the index you can check the indexes `dirty bit` and check to see if that page of the index has been updated and just copy the whole dirty index page to disk. No need to walk the tree, just the index of index pages. [I suggested something similar to a CUDA memory copy problem - I must be a bit of a one trick pony  :) ]

Answer (score 0):

Are the data (key, value) pairs kept separately on disk, or do you need to persist them along with the index? Do you keep the data itself in-memory, or is only the index memory-resident, while the data is on disk? If the whole dataset is memory-resident, don't persist the tree structure at all. Just save the ordered list of (key, value) pairs and rebuild the tree on load. I never used that library, but any reasonable B-tree implementation should be able to build an in-memory B-tree out of a pre-sorted stream of records very efficiently.