# Looking for a disk-bound b-tree example

Tags: c#, algorithm, disk, b-tree

Maybe my google-foo just isn't up to snuff, but I'm wanting to play with a b-tree alogrithm that is bound to disk. Since most tutorials and examples are on-memory, they assume random access memory in which changing nodes in a tree is simple enough, but other than rather I/O intensive rewriting or using memory-mapped files, I can't think of a good approach.

Theory would be fine, C# or Java would be even better.

**EDIT:** I apologize for the lack of clarity. I am not looking for a product or code base to use, but an example or illustrative codebase to better understand how one would go about building a disk-backed b-tree.

Comment: Many databases (even just key/value stores) use B-Trees or a close variant. It may be worth looking at something like HSQL, Derby, or SQLite code. A good bit or work goes into juggling the pages to minimize IO and this could be seen in a "real" codebase. I would also suspect there is a writeup or small project on CodePlex.

Comment: I would prefer a more illustrative approach. I'm not looking for an optimized implementation, but a general approach that I can experiment with.

Comment: Anyways, I don't think that something in C# or Java is useful. You need something very low level... I worked with Tokyo Cabinet to benchmark sequential/random IO reads. Ideally the size of your nodes should be equal to a disk page. However, at the end you don't have a huge control over that. You can set node sizes but the disk is again another abstraction level and you don't know what is going on there ... And the different levels of caches make your life worse :D

Comment: The [Wiki B-Tree entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) has a very good "why B-Trees" under the "The Database Problem" section. Hopefully this will help show (in a very high level) how B-Tree nodes are mapped to disk blocks and why this is beneficial.

Comment: The comment discussion here has been most enlightening, unfortunately, that leaves me with an answer to my question, but not an answer that applies and warrants being marked accepted.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fastest Key Value DB (which also contains a Key Value DB which works with B+Trees) is Tokyo Cabinet (or Kyoto Cabinet) :). I have worked with it when I was benchmarking B+Trees and the code is easy to understand. It's written in C but it has also Java bindings...
Tokyo Cabinet:
http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/

And Berkley DB also works with a B+Tree. However, when I was benchmarking Berkley DB, it was very slow compared to Tokyo Cabinet though...
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html

Comment: I've looked at both Berkeley DB and Tokyo Cabinet's source code and while they both may be great products, as a code base to learn the underlying fundamentals from, they did not help me :(

Comment: Maybe you should look at the fundamental specifications (http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html). This explains in detail what the code does...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, see top the 2nd,3rd,4th & 5th results from [google](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=disk+btree&oq=disk+btree&aq=0&aqi=g1g-m1g-b1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=23509l33283l0l28l21l0l6l6l2l367l2777l2.8.3.2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6ef50d66b38089c9&biw=1228&bih=867).

Secondly, see this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872070/saving-btrees-to-a-disk-file-and-read-it) with very similar question.

Thirdly, if you use MSSQL as an example you can read some stuff [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280360.aspx) and visualize the pages as described [here](http://mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1578) (just like cache line split it's important to minimize such splits). Also MSSQL for example imposes a size limit of the data that can be indexed which is 8k = to the page size.

Fourthly, see the answer of my question which I had to ask just be able to provide this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172754/what-commands-are-available-to-visualize-the-data-pages-on-mssql-server) 
Alternatively you can use a hex editor to view the database files and see how things are mapped but that's extreme.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't explaining it properly. I don't want to serialize the btree to disk and back. I want to have a disk backed b-tree, i.e. as i edit the disk representation changes, as i traverse, i traverse on disk. and all those links talk about on-memory representations.

Comment: @Arne Claasen Consider that a non-leaf node (cluster) is a disk-page  and that each child node is a fixed size within that non-leaf node. Then given the page # (needs not be sequential!) and the child # a particular non-leaf (and/or child) can be looked up. The "trick" is to make sure that page's are already loaded in memory if *they need to be* -- e.g. read-ahead of sequential pages. A really smarter engine might try to reduce fragmentation; or have this as a periodic "rebuild" phase.

Comment: @Arne Claassen This "block" structure of a B-Tree and how it fits into IO is one reason why it is popular or such tasks.

Comment: So basically i do manual memory mapping around nodes with file system pointers? Treat the disk as the heap and manually track where i can put things